# Mount VHD using GRUB2 loopback command

Tags: bootloader, vhd, grub

I need to mount a VHD file at grub2 command prompt.

I tries using "loopback" command as shown below:

```
grub > insmod ntfs
grub > insmod ntldr
grub > loopback loop (hd0,1)/test.vhd
grub > ls (loop)/
error: unknown filesystem
```

I tried both "static" and "dynamic" vhd and both VHD file had ntfs partitioned data.

I guess VHD files have some header data which makes the filesystem not recognizable after "loopback" mount. I am able to mount and access "iso" files using same set of commands.

Is my guess correct? If so, is there a way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your guess is half right:

Whilst VHD supports a linear "fixed" storage model, which actually is just  the raw data as it would be stored on a "real" hard drive, followed by a VHD footer, this is most probably not usually the case; VHD supports dynamically resizing images, which of course aren't linear internally, so you can't simply boot into that.

Comment: I tried both "fixed" and "dynamic" vhd models and it resulted in same issue in both the cases.

Comment: "fixed" should actually work, if wikipedia is right about VHD. So I recommend investigating loopback on NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get the data from the loop mounted data with following change in the above pasted grub command.

```
grub > insmod ntfs
grub > loopback loop (hd0,1)/test.vhd
grub > ls (loop,1)/
```

The file "test.vhd" was a single partitioned VHD file.

**NOTE:** Only "fixed" or "static" model VHDs work. I could not get it working with "dynamic" VHD (as suggested by @Marcus Müller )

Thanks for the help. Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score -1):

To use VHD disks on grub2 need:

```
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
loopback loop /point/where/disk.vhd tdisk=VHD
ls (loop,msdos1)/
```